# "Multi quidem facilius se abstinent ut non utantur, quam temperent ut bene utantur" (the usage of comparatives)

Tags: grammar-identification, comparative

From Augustine *De Bono Coniugali*:

> Multi quidem facilius se abstinent ut non utantur, quam temperent ut bene utantur.

While the meaning of the sentence is clear, I'm not sure about the grammatical construction here. As *facilius* seems to be the the modifier of the entire *se abstinent ut non utantur*, but then I would expect, as some English translations render this ("To many, it is easier .."), to see a kind of dative like *multis*.

Generally, What are the ways to construct sentences like:

> It is easier for him to read than to write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two basic options that come to mind are:

1. Ille facilius legit quam scribit.
2. Illi facilius est legere quam scribere.

The second one corresponds with the typical English phrasing.
The first one is "he reads easily" rather than "it is easy for him to read", but I see no difference in meaning in Latin.

The structural difference is significant.
In the first one the subject is *ille*, in the second one it is the infinitive and *ille* is just a beneficiary.
The dative is not a valid choice if the verb is in a personal form.
Notice also that in the first option *facilius* is a comparative adverb whereas in the second one it is the neuter nominative.
Which option flows best depends on the flow of the narrative and the structures around it.

Comment: Thanks. Reading your answer, now I see I was misreading *facilius*, to be the nominative of *facilior*, but it is rather the comparative of *facile* the adverb.

Comment: @d_e Indeed, *facilius* plays different roles in the two approaches. I added a note on that to help future readers.